# Embedded Google form does not display across browsers

Tags: google-docs

I have a form for my sports club embedded in this page: http://www.cork-boston-gfc.com/join.html

The form in question is: https://docs.google.com/a/gaa.ie/spreadsheet/embeddedform?formkey=dEFGd0pfUjRKRGg4VWhXZzFRU0VmS3c6MQ

I can view it with no problems in Chrome on one PC, but on another (with same version) I get an Error 111.

In Firefox I cannot see it at all.

And in IE, there is also a browser-related error.

At the moment, I only have the document shared to myself as owner, but I have the Accepting Responses box ticked.

Can anyone help me here in identifying what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I can answer this again myself.

Because our Google Docs integration is through a third party, there was a special restriction in place that is not part of the normal Google Forms. Removing this resolved the issue.